# rails 3 has_one radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, radio-button, has-one

Having problems creating radio buttons in a form using has_one

Model

```
Class User
has_one :role
accepts_nested_attributes_for :role

Class Role
attr_accessible :name
belongs_to :user
```

Controller

```
@user = build_role
```

Form for radio buttons

```
<div class="field">
 <% Role.offset(1).all.each do |role_fields| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag "user[role_fields_id][]", role_fields.id, @user.role_id == role_fields.id %>
  <%= role_fields.name %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Getting the error

```
undefined method `role_id' for #<User id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I'm sure I set up the relationship in the controller, why is this not working?

Comment: Does your `User` model have a `role_id` column?

Comment: Why would my User model need the role_id column? @Zajn

Comment: I was under the assumption that you were storing a `role_id` for each User, but what Geoff said in his answer makes sense. Seeing `@user.role_id` made me think you were trying to access a `role_id` attribute on that User instance, since according to your error, there's no `role_id` method for User instances.

Comment: @Zajn, I should have included it in my answer, but there was a section in the documentation about `has_one` vs. `belongs_to` that made it clear that there would be no `role_id` in this direction. (I had to look it up to confirm it to myself before answering.)

Comment: @Geoff, Right, I just wasn't sure if by chance he had mixed up his associations and used `has_one` where he meant `belongs_to`. I know I get them mixed up all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "user[role_fields_id][]", role_fields.id, @user.role_id == role_fields.id %>
```

Should be corrected to this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "user[role_fields_id][]", role_fields.id, @user.role.id == role_fields.id %>
```

I hope that helps.